# Update Build Pipeline variables from .Net code

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfs-sdk

We have a build definition i Azure DevOps that creates a docker image and pushes it to Azure Container Registry. The definition has a pipeline variable that has to be inserted at build time. I have to queue the build from my .Net code. I can get the definition but don't see how to update the pipeline variable.

```
VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("",persAccToken);
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(uri, credentials);
BuildHttpClient buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
BuildDefinition def = buildClient.GetDefinitionAsync(projectName, definitionId).Result;
```

The pipeline variable is "settable at queue time". However I don't find a way to do it from my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BuildDefinition has property Variables that contains pipeline variables. That variable can be removed and than added with new value or updated

```
BuildDefinitionVariable bdv = new BuildDefinitionVariable { AllowOverride = true, 
                               IsSecret = false, Value = "new-vaule" };

def.Variables.Remove("variable-name");
def.Variables.Add("variable-name", bdv);
buildClient.UpdateDefinitionAsync(def, projectName, def.Id);
```

Comment: One note about the solution, when you call UpdateDefinitionAsync() it will return a new build def object which has an updated revision number.  You'll want to use that object when queue'ing up a build not the original object.

Answer (score 0):

> Update Build Pipeline variables from .Net code

As workaround, you can update a variable value by emitting the following with Powershell scripts:

```
"##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"
```

Check the document [Logging Commands](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) for some more details.

Then you could call this `.ps1` with your .Net code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I need a pure .Net code. Found solution myself